# How to add a back button in pygame

Tags: python, button, pygame

So I decided to make a back button for by game in pygame because it has a main menu and lots of other menus within it(such as a help menu). I already have the code for making a button, but all I need is some kind of function that allows the button function like a back button.

Here is my button function that I normally use to make a button:

```
def button(x, y, w, h, inactive, active, action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y + h > mouse[1] > y:
        gameDisplay.blit(active, (x, y))
        if click[0] == 1 and action is not None:
            action()
    else:
        gameDisplay.blit(inactive, (x, y))
```

Here's what each parameter in `button()` means:

- x: x-coordinate of the button
- y: y-coordinate of the button
- w: width of button image
- h: height of button image
- active: picture of button when the mouse is hovering over it
- inactive: picture of button when it is idle
- action: the function to be executed when the button is clicked(this should be a function)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does the back button function differently than any other button? What does the back button do?

Answer (score 0):

What I really recommend is the `pygame-menu` package for creating menu. It has quite a big variety of widgets and working workflow. Probably based on their github you might find what you are looking for.

[pygame-menu github](https://github.com/ppizarror/pygame-menu)

I don't understand what is the difference between yours 'back button' and 'normal button', but this page might help.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a back button which lets you get back to the main menu then you just need to reference the main menu function as the action:

```
backButton = button(x, y, w, h, inactive, active, mainMenu()):
```